# Why does this instance fail the coverage condition?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, functional-dependencies

Why does the following instance declaration fail the coverage condition in the absence of `UndecidableInstances`?  It seems that if the functional dependency is satisfied in the context then it is satisfied in the new instance.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

class Foo a b | a -> b where

instance (Foo a b, Foo a' b') => Foo (a, a') (b, b') where
```

If I try to replicate the same thing with a type family there is no problem.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

type family Bar a

type instance Bar (a, b) = (Bar a, Bar b)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers.  I guess I've still got a lot to learn about typeclasses.  I'm picking Ben's answer just because it was the first one.  Thanks both for your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it's that constraints on instances aren't actually taken into account when selecting an instance. They become additional constraints to be proved at each use site, rather than limiting the applicability of the instance.

So your instance declaration is kind of equivalent to `instance Foo (a, b) (c, d)`, which rather obviously fails the coverage condition.

Adding the `(Foo a b, Foo a' b')` only makes it so that some of the *uses* of the instance would result in "no such instance" errors, it doesn't actually change the types for which your instance will be selected.

Answer (score 3):

From the GHC [docs](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html#undecidable-instances):

> The Coverage Condition. For each functional dependency, tvsleft ->
>   tvsright, of the class, every type variable in S(tvsright) must appear
>   in S(tvsleft), where S is the substitution mapping each type variable
>   in the class declaration to the corresponding type in the instance
>   declaration.

In your class you have `a -> b`, so `tvsleft = a` and `tvsright = b`.
The substitution `S` maps `a` into `S(a)=(a,a')` and `b` into `S(b)=(b,b')`.

So, we find type variables in `S(tvsright)=S(b)=(b,b')` (both `b` and `b'`) which do not
appear in `S(tvsleft)=S(a)=(a,a')`. Hence the coverage condition fails.

As @Ben said, the coverage condition does not take the context into account: 
only the instance head matters.